# ProgressBar progress disappears when going to third Fragment in the ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-progressbar

I know that when using the sliding tabs design pattern using ViewPager and Fragments, the ViewPager can only deal with two Fragments at a time and once it goes to the third, the views get re-created. The problem I am having is that everything else is getting re-created except the ProgressBars that I am using as static meters to indicate values. Does anyone know how to get this working properly? I assume it is something to do with saving the state of the ProgressBar and I know that this isn't the conventional way to use a ProgressBar as it is meant for display downloading and loading progress.

Please can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want your fragments to be recreated ? This sounds like a very bad idea. To prevent that behaviour, you can set the number of pages of your `ViewPager` :

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
mViewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(3);
```

This will prevent the `ViewPager` from destroying off-screen `Fragments`.

Comment: I just found this out before you answered and it works. I don't want to re-create the fragments and this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.